# Missing toolbar in Android Studio?

Tags: android-layout, toolbar

So I was making some layouts and one day noticed my toolbar was missing for some of my newer files. These are xml files that are shown in design view.

The image with the blue arrow shows the toolbar I am refering to, that is present in one of my files. The image with the yellow question mark shows the toolbar that is missing in another file.

I have looked around but can't find how to restore it, not even sure how I accidentally removed it in the first place. Any suggestions on how to bring it back?

[image: Arrow is pointing to toolbar]

[image: Question mark is pointing to missing toolbar]

UPDATE:
Problem has been fixed and here is what it looks like to "convert the view" and get the toolbar back.

[image: Toolbar is back]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toolbar that is missing is associated with a constraint based layout, and it missing because the layout for your new view does not have a constraint based layout.

You can right click the view and click `Convert to ConstraintBasedLayout` in the dropdown menu to restore that bar.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I can see the toolbar now. I will add that clicking convert view, brings up a couple different options like constraint, linear, relative etc and each changes what the toolbar has in it.